# How can I construct a google drive URL that highlights the file, and prompts for login if I'm logged out

Tags: url, google-drive-api

I'm trying to construct a URL much like this one:

`https://drive.google.com/drive/u/mygmailaccount@gmail.com?usp=drive-viewer#my-drive?action=locate&id=18Ykr-T-5z3ZPMNGfbkq78KacSOo08XDVOT-OswTDmug&parent=0ANZyfBu_UgzTUk9PVA`

This does most of what I want. It will open google drive, with that file highlighted and in the context of the folder containing it. It will also select the correct account if I have *multiple* accounts logged in (including this account). Below is an example of the correct behaviour. Google drive comes up with the correct account loaded, and the file specified by the ID in the url is highlighted (In this case, lazyname19.png)

[image: specific file highlighted]

The issue is that it will 404 if that is the **only** account that I have logged in (which I find super strange) *and* it will not prompt me to log in with the correct account under any circumstances. Here is what happens if I traverse the *same* link, but without that user logged in:

[image: 404]

Ideally there should be some way to construct a URL that will just do the right thing if the given account is logged in, and prompt the user to sign in with the correct account otherwise.

I would be eternally grateful if anyone can tell me **where this stuff is documented** (https://developers.google.com/drive/ doesn't even touch the subject). Any information that would help me solve this specific issue would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you mean "highlight the file"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'll add a couple screenshots for clarity

Comment: There we go. Screenshots added.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out that a decent way to do this is to actually try to hit the folders endpoint rather than specifying the email address:

`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ANZyfBu_UgzTUk9PVA?usp=drive-viewer#my-drive?action=locate&id=18Ykr-T-5z3ZPMNGfbkq78KacSOo08XDVOT-OswTDmug&parent=0ANZyfBu_UgzTUk9PVA`

This has the desired effect of switching to a user with access (if there is one logged in), and giving a decent message in the case that none of the logged in users have access:

[image: login prompt]